# CSS transition in Chrome stops or is jerky while an image is being rendered

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, css-transitions, image-gallery

I'm working on a touch-enabled html5+css3 image gallery. The targeted devices are primarily tablets and other mobile devices. The images are quite big (around 1000x1500) and a gallery can be from 100 to 200 images. The gallery is basically a carousel and a user can swipe left and right to move through the gallery. The way it works is that the images are laid out in a div (named #ribbon) that is transitioned left when you swipe to the left, thus sliding the next image into view.

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div id="ribbon">
    <div class="slide"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src=""></div>
```

To limit the bandwidth consumption and initial load time, just the first 10-15 image containers are actually inserted into the html. When you swipe to the centre of the carousel, the first image container skips to the end of the carousel and a new image is loaded when the animation ends. In Safari and on iOS this works smooth as butter.

I know better than to touch the DOM unnecessarily, especially while CSS transitions are running and the code should be mostly optimal in this regard. But nevertheless, in Chrome (both desktop and Android) there is a hiccup in animation every time the next image src is set. I can see this in developer tools, the events that apparently cause the hiccups are image resizing and rendering.

To try and make the animation smoother, each time the drag event is started, all the images (except the current, left and right) are set to a white gif pixel. This also helps when you swipe fast through the gallery, because it skips loading unnecessary images.

Is there a way to mitigate this issue?

### jsFiddle example

A simplified example. Not sure if this is good enough to demonstrate the problem, but I trie to time the swipe events to interrupt image decoding and rendering.

http://jsfiddle.net/YevMC/

### Additional notes

- I tried resizing the image via canvas and setting the image src to canvas.toDataUrl(), but it doesn't seem to help. Maybe I should try web-workers?
- I'm already using 3D transforms.
- All the CSS hacks are applied, *translate3d*, *perspective: 1000* (which seems to help a lot in Chrome).
- *backface-visibility: hidden* causes unwanted side-effects, e.g. only showing a part of an image.
- Enabling 3D on the img elements themselves helps on chrome, but has a detrimental effect on animation performance in iOS. Luckily there is the window.chrome object that makes it easy to detect chrome.

### Chrome Timeline

[image: Chrome timeline shows image painting taking around 200ms]

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Maybe I could make a working example to demonstrate the problem. It will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using requestAnimationFrame rather than setTimeout